# Web Services + Android

Tags: java, php, android, json, rest

I'm starter with web services (and practically in web development) and I'd like to connect my Android app with a web server.  I have readed that the best way for doing that is implementing a REST+JSON server.
I have no full control over the server (just a control panel) and is no dedicated for me.
I had thought implementing that with PHP. Is ok? If yes, should I manually pharse the JSON chains of text or there are any library for simplify this step?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In PHP there are a few libraries for creating/using JSON.  This [link](http://gggeek.altervista.org/sw/article_20061113.html) has a nice comparison of many of these popular libraries.

Android has native support for JSON.  [Here is the package](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) with the pertinent classes.

Answer (score 2):

For PHP you only need to know json_encode() and json_decode() this will turn an array into JSON and vice-versa.

And as per @nicholas Android has native support.

I have a well-used REST class that I can give you too if needed.